# What Does Django static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) Actually DO?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am using Django 2.2. From the Django *Managing static files* [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

> If you use django.contrib.staticfiles as explained above, runserver
>   will do this automatically when DEBUG is set to True. If you don’t
>   have django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS, you can still
>   manually serve static files using the django.views.static.serve()
>   view.
>
> This is not suitable for production use! For some common deployment
>   strategies, see Deploying static files.
>
> For example, if your STATIC_URL is defined as /static/, you can do
>   this by adding the following snippet to your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

> **Note**
>
> This helper function works only in debug mode and only if the given
>   prefix is local (e.g. /static/) and not a URL (e.g.
>   http://static.example.com/).
>
> Also this helper function only serves the actual STATIC_ROOT folder;
>   it doesn’t perform static files discovery like
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.

**My Interpretation**

1. [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#static) is a helper function that serves files from the `STATIC_ROOT` **during development** (is this True?)
2. [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#static) only works when `debug = True`
3. [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#static) only works with a local prefix like `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
4. When `DEBUG` is set to True and I use and setup the staticfiles app as explained in the documentation, if I do `python manage.py runserver` to start the local server, the serving of static files will be handled automatically (true??)

**My Questions**

1. What EXACTLY does adding `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to your project's `urls.py` DO?
2. Is it true that [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#static) serves static files locally from the `STATIC_ROOT` directory? To test this theory, after running `collectstatic`, I then deleted the `static` directories to see if the static files still load fine (from the STATIC_ROOT) and they DON'T! Why?
3. How can I **verify** that Django is loading the static files from my STATIC_ROOT location... and not the static directories in my project and apps??
4. Why is adding `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to `urlpatterns` necessary if Django serves static files automatically (mentioned in documentation)?

**Example**

[image: Example Django Project]

settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'puppies.apps.PuppiesConfig'
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = 'c:/lkdsjfkljsd_cdn'
```

In all my templates, I'm using `{% load static %}`.

Then I do: `python manage.py collectstatic`

[image: STATIC_ROOT]

At this point, it doesn't seem to matter if I have the below in my `urls.py` or not - my static files still load BUT I don't know if they're coming from my project's static directories or my STATIC_ROOT (c:/lkdsjfkljsd_cdn):

```
if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Lastly, if I delete those static directories in my project, all css, js and images don't work which leads me to believe that my Django project is loading static files from my project's static directories, NOT the STATIC_ROOT.

So, again, **how can I tell Django to load the static files from my STATIC_ROOT location... and not the static directories in my project and apps??** OR, do I misunderstand that Django isn't supposed to load files from my STATIC_ROOT location locally?

*Edit (adding HTML image)

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are mixing up few things. Let me clarify.

#### [**`static:`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#static)

As per documentation, it provides URL pattern for serving static file. If you go to the [**`implementation`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/static.py#L27), then you will see:

```
return [
        re_path(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(prefix.lstrip('/')), view, kwargs=kwargs),
]
```

What it does is, it removes forward slash from left of the prefix(ie converts `/static/` to `static/`), and then there is a view(which is [**`serve`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve)) who does the pulling files.

#### [**`serve:`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve)

This function does the serving files. It will serve files from a document root.

#### [**`runserver:`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#runserver)

`runserver` command runs the django development server. If you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` installed in **`INSTALLED_APPS`**, then it will automatically serve static files. If you don't want to serve static, then use `runserver --nostatic`. `collectstatic` or `STATIC_ROOT` has no relation to this command.

#### [**`collectstatic`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic):

This command collects all static files from different `STATIC_DIRS`, and put them in folder which is defined by `STATIC_ROOT`. `collectstatic` is very useful in production deployment, when you are using a reverse proxy server like NGINX or Apache etc. NGINX/Apache/Varnish uses that folder (where collectstatic stored the static files) as root and serve static from it. It is not recommended to use `runserver` in production. You can use gunicorn/uwsgi to serve django. But gunicorn/uwsgi does not serve static files, hence using reverse proxy server to serve static files.

#### **`finally:`**

To answer your questions:

1. No you don't have to put that in your code, unless you are not adding `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. No
3. You don't need to. STATIC_ROOT is used for different purpose
4. It is not. But for serving MEDIA files, you can add the following pattern:

   ```
   if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += [
           re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
               'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
           }),
       ]
   ```

In production, media files should be served by reverse proxy server as well.

Comment: yes, of course. But again, using that would not be recommended for production setup.

Comment: can you check if you are getting static files correctly like `127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/some.js`?

Comment: I meant are you getting 404 at `localhost:8000/static/puppies/js/base.js` :) ?

Comment: Umm, is it after you remove the static files from project and add `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`?

Comment: I think so(or atleast as per docs). But I need to check the implementations of django.contrib.staticfiles to be 100% sure.