# Django: Why do I need these in my setttings.py and urls.py

Tags: python, django

I am watching an online tutorial on making a video subscription website, and somehow these codes should appear in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root'),
]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')
```

In my urls.py, these codes appear as well...

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am quite a beginner in django and python, can anyone please explain to me why do I need these codes?

Comment: To tell Django where to find your static (css, js) files and user-uploaded files (media)

Answer (score 2):

Django's staticfiles are all those files that specify the "look and feel" of your website (css and js files, as well as images). Check out this part of the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial06) from Django's official website. The MEDIA_URL part is all about storing and serving images **uploaded by users**; be careful though, this only works during development (DEBUG = True) and is not suitable for production use. Refer to [this site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/) to see how to serve your staticfiles during deployment.

So what you are specifying in that code are the locations Django should look in for loading all your images, js and css files, given you are in development.

Answer (score 0):

`static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` is probably not necessary - look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56353153/1412564).

`static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` is necessary for displaying media files in development. You should not use it in production, as it requires `settings.DEBUG` to be true. In production you should configure your web server to serve static and media files directly. For example in Nginx, you can define `location /static` and `location /media` in your configuration file.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) for more details.